# How to display cells only if a different cell is faults over a range of data?

Tags: excel

I am  trying to build a list of all the accounts not invoiced at any given time in excel. I have tried to do

```
=If(B5:K5="no",Transpose(B3:K3),"")
```

This hasn't worked I have been able to do a count formula so I have a total of how many accounts are not invoiced but I want it to display the name of the account in row 3 if row 5 is "no". I only want to display accounts that are marked no for invoiced not the whole list of accounts. Is there a way to do this across a range? I have added a picture of what I hope to accomplish in a simplified way.

[image: transposed list of accounts to invoice]

Comment: Why not transpose the entire table and filter on what would then be the "Invoice Confirmation" column?

Comment: I have multiple sheets for different channels so I am trying to set a separate sheet with just the account names for each channel. Also the sheet I am working with has a lot more values than the simplified version I posted.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to do this across a range?

In one line? AFAIK nope.

Try :

Put `=IF(B5="Yes",A7,A7+1)` in B7 and drag rightwards.

Put `=MAX(7:7)&" match only"` in A8.

Put `=IF((ROW()-8)<=MAX($7:$7),ROW()-8,"")` in A9, then put `=IFERROR(INDEX($3:$3,MATCH(ROW()-8,$7:$7,0)),"")` in B9 and drag both downwards.

I hope that gets what you closer to what you need.